# How to store length of values in a column as a new cclumn of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
data = {'CHROM':['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr1', 'chr3', 'chr1'],
        'POS':[939570,3411794,1043223,22511093,24454031],
        'REF':['T', 'T', 'CCT', 'CTT', 'CT'],
        'ALT':['TCCCTGGAGGACC', 'C', 'C', 'CT', 'CTT']
       }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2
```

It looks as follows:

```
    CHROM   POS        REF  ALT
0   chr1    939570     T    TCCCTGGAGGACC
1   chr2    3411794    T    C
2   chr1    1043223    CCT  C
3   chr3    22511093   CTT  CT
4   chr1    24454031   CT   CTT
```

I want find length of each value in df2['REF'] and store it in new columns such that the dataframe looks like as follows:

```
    CHROM   POS        REF  ALT            ref_len
0   chr1    939570     T    TCCCTGGAGGACC   1
1   chr2    3411794    T    C               1
2   chr1    1043223    CCT  C               3
3   chr3    22511093   CTT  CT              3
4   chr1    24454031   CT   CTT             2
```

I tried as follows:
`df2['Test'] = len(df2['REF'])` but it did not give me the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need [`len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) method:

```
df2['ref_len'] = df2['REF'].str.len()
```

Now if you print `df2` you will get your desired output:

```
  CHROM       POS  REF            ALT  ref_len
0  chr1    939570    T  TCCCTGGAGGACC        1
1  chr2   3411794    T              C        1
2  chr1   1043223  CCT              C        3
3  chr3  22511093  CTT             CT        3
4  chr1  24454031   CT            CTT        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
In [2434]: df2['ref_len'] = df2.REF.str.len()

In [2435]: df2
Out[2435]: 
  CHROM       POS  REF            ALT  ref_len
0  chr1    939570    T  TCCCTGGAGGACC        1
1  chr2   3411794    T              C        1
2  chr1   1043223  CCT              C        3
3  chr3  22511093  CTT             CT        3
4  chr1  24454031   CT            CTT        2
```